# Issue related to concept of abstraction in OOPs

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, abstract

I was reading OOPs Concepts from internet using articles.

In one of article, I have read following about abstraction:

> If we have a method named "CalculatePrice" inside the "Billing" class,
>   we are not concerned about the calculations inside the
>   "CalculatePrice" method. We just pass the necessary parameters and get
>   the output. We hide the implementation of "Calculate Price".

so my question is : In C#, we are using dlls and namespace and calls the specific methods. can we say that, dlls and namespaces are the concept of  Abstractions ??

Thanks

Comment: That question makes no sense. What does the implementation of a method have to do with namespaces? Namespaces are simply a way to segment your classes into logic units. The implementation of a method has nothing to do with this.

Comment: my meant was when we use dlls we must have to write "using Namespace" like "using system" at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Basically, no. Namespaces are not the concept of abstraction. Your obviously misunderstanding what abstraction is.

Comment: The article is about classes, C# has classes. No need to find other elements as equivalent.

Comment: and only after using namespace we can create an object of class and after then we can call the specific method using object of class. so dlls and namespace are connected with eachother.

Comment: if namespaces are not conecpt of abstaction then dlls are ?

Comment: **No** neither of these are.

Comment: Namespaces are an optional way to organize classes. You're chasing ghosts.

Comment: Look if we talk about packaging something ,wrapping ,arranging or delivering that package we talk about Dll and Namespace in which Namespace is just how a Post office separates mails on the basis of Pin-Code (or any logic you want).

Comment: Namespaces in .NET are the opposite of an abstraction. If I have two classes called `A`, I can use their namespaces to identify which one I'm referring to. A namespace is a way of concretely identifying something, not a way of abstracting it.

Comment: @Liam You are mistaken with your assertion that neither is an abstraction. A dll can, and often is, an abstraction in C#. Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You should generally just think of dll-files and namespaces as ways to organize your projects.

The abstraction of `CalculatePrice` consists simply of the "hiding" of it's logic inside the method. When another piece of code calls the method, it does not care what happens inside it - it is only interested in the result.

Abstractions in C# (and .Net in general) are made using things like **Classes**, **Interfaces**, **Abstract Classes**, and method and properties that are defined and/or implemented in these.

Your focus should be on these concepts, and on how they are used together in different "patterns" to solve various types of problems.

To expand just a little on your example: If `CalculatePrice` was defined in an interface, then calling code would "talk to" that interface, without caring about what was behind it. An implementation of that interface - the code that actually performs the logic - could be anything. It could change, and keep changing, as long as it fulfills the requirements (the "contract") defined in the interface, since that would allow the calling code to keep using it.. and *that* is how abstraction works in C#.

Comment: I can see there is one downvote here. It would be interesting to know the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that there are four answers all saying "no". In reality, the answer is "sometimes". If the implementation of `CalculatePrice` relies on another class, which is marked as internal, then its assembly does form part of the abstraction, since internal classes are only accessible to other classes in that assembly.

Namespaces in .NET do not form part of any abstraction though. In other languages they can, as `internal` can be tied to namespaces, but that is not how .NET languages work.

Such information hiding is the most basic form of abstraction though. C#'s most powerful abstraction tools are interfaces, support for dependency injection and its treatment of methods as values. If you are interested in understanding more about abstraction in C#, they are the three areas to focus on.

Comment: Interesting point, But: If a class is internal, it will be invisible to the calling code. In theory, it could be replaced without the calling party noticing at all. Is is then still a part of the abstraction, just because it is being hidden? Not sure how I would define this, myself.. (And either way - this is probably a little beyond the context of the OP here, though it may be a good point :) ).

Comment: @Kjartan Hiding the inner workings away from the public API is an abstraction. If it's invisible to the calling code, then it's abstracted. However, we can aim far higher than simple hiding with abstractions, instead aiming for decoupling, such as through the use of interfaces. The other answers here seem to treat decoupling and abstraction as the same thing. This is a mistake in my view.

Comment: The question was about concept. " can we say that, dlls and namespaces are the concept of Abstractions ?" The answer is no.

Comment: @James I think you are being too literal with the words of someone who does not have English as their first language.

Answer (score 0):

> so my question is : In C#, we are using dlls and namespace and calls the specific methods. can we say that, dlls and namespaces are the concept of Abstractions ??

No.